# Error selecting interface with "vnstat --face"

Tags: vnstat

When changing the interface with the command `vnstat --iface` it shows me the following error `Error: Interface for --iface missing.`

Comment: `--iface` requires an argument - the interface you are going to be looking at.  What's the full command you're executing?

Comment: it show me this ------ andy@andy-pc:~$ vnstat --iface usb0
Error: Interface "usb0" not found in database.

Comment: the interface has to be an interface on the system.  Is `usb0` an actual interface on the computer?  Usually, that's not how network interfaces are named.

Comment: Assuming that your wired network interface is eth0, first you must --add that interface to the vnstat database, then you can get stats on it, after it's had some time to accumulate data. See `man vnstat` for more info, and see the examples at the end of the man page.